# Как определить указывает компас на GPS метку или нет

Tags: android, геометрия, геолокация, gps, координаты

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить:
Есть android устройство, есть данные о направлении поворота устройства относительно севера от 0...360 градусов. 0 это север. Есть GPS координаты устройства и координаты произвольной точки в радиусе 10 км. Вопрос - как определить направлено ли устройство камерой (задней частью) в сторону точки GPS или нет. Для решения я использовал нахождение угла между 2-х катетов, но так и не достиг корректной работы. Может кто даст ссылку на рабочий пример? Заранее спасибо!

```
 public double getDegree(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2){

        double c,k,tn;
        double a=0, b=0;

        a=lat1-lat2;  //Длинна катета1
        b=lng1-lng2;  //Длинна катета2

        c=Math.sqrt((a*a)+(b*b));
        k=a/b;
        tn=Math.atan(k);  
        return Math.toDegrees(tn);  //Нашли угол в градусах
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Направление к цели вычисляется вот так

```
//gpsList - список точек целей
//TARGET_LATITUDE TARGET_LONGITUDE - координаты устройства
public double calculateAzimuthToPoint(int position) {
        double dX = gpsList.get(position).getLat() - TARGET_LATITUDE;
        double dY = gpsList.get(position).getLng() - TARGET_LONGITUDE;

        double phiAngle;
        double tanPhi;
        double azimuth = 0;

        tanPhi = Math.abs(dY / dX);
        phiAngle = Math.atan(tanPhi);
        phiAngle = Math.toDegrees(phiAngle);

        if (dX > 0 && dY > 0) { // I quater
            return azimuth = phiAngle;
        } else if (dX < 0 && dY > 0) { // II
            return azimuth = 180 - phiAngle;
        } else if (dX < 0 && dY < 0) { // III
            return azimuth = 180 + phiAngle;
        } else if (dX > 0 && dY < 0) { // IV
            return azimuth = 360 - phiAngle;
        }

        return phiAngle;  //Угол 0...360 указывающий на цель относительно устройства
    }
```

Очень помогла статья https://www.netguru.co/blog/augmented-reality-mobile-android